# Titanium appcelerator : Twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I want to share my application data via twitter, I have created customer key as well as consumer secret key. Everything works well but as soon as twitter windows opens it crashes every time after some time after displaying the login screen of twitter. Below is the code that I have used in order to open twitter window

```
 var twitter = new BirdHouse({
consumer_key: "consumer key",
consumer_secret: "consumer secret"  
    });
twitter.tweet();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make user login once user logs-in you need to call method tweet

before this there is method called authorize or with similar name first hit that to make user login

also you can use alloy frame work to twitter integration it has twitter in built

```
function authorize(callback) {
            if (!authorized) {
                    get_request_token(callback); // get_request_token or a function it calls will call callback

            } else {
                    // execute the callback function
                    if(typeof(callback)=='function'){
                            callback(authorized);
                    }
            }

            return authorized;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide code for login in code as I am very new to Titanium and have gone through many document and I got this code.

Comment: and let me tell you that birdhouse uses twitter api 1.1 that is now deprecated so please make sure that you work with some birdhouse version that uses twitter api 1.2 otherwise you will stuck after putting in lot of effort
better use alloy framework
if you still want to continue with birdhouse search for method authorize in birdhouse.js file and make call to that method

Comment: Bt acutally I got it from net and it have been specified that

Comment: // Author: Joseph D. Purcell, iEntry Inc
// Version: 0.9
// Modified: May 2011

Comment: I updated my code please find that method in birdhouse js file you will login through this but you can't tweet
In case you want to tweet using this and do not wnat to use alloyn please update tweet method of birdhouse to hit new api
and don'ty forget to accept answer if it helps :P

Comment: Y i have found that code in birdhouse.js and its jst same as u have mentioned over here. I have authorize(callback) named function in birdhouse.js file. Unable to get what should I pass in "callback" argument. I would surely accept answer.

Comment: callback is actually a function you  can make a function and pass function name as arguement that will becalled on successful login

Comment: no, do something like 
function callback(e){
alert("done");
}
and call twitter.authorize(callback);
cheers

Comment: still unclear. . .twitter.authorize(callback) that is in my post_to_twitter function. wat abt that ?

Comment: I mean to say. where to specify  function callback(e){ alert("done"); }  function ?

Comment: write in any where in you file where you call authorize function

Comment: I have written  function callback(e){ alert("done"); } in birdhouse.js file and called twitter.authorize(callback); in post_to_twitter function. But here in this method i am receiving "call back is not defined" . .

Comment: why do you write it in birdhouse .js ?
write in file where you call birdhouse where you define twitter

Comment: ok. .i have written that function where i am defining twitter function. But in doing so as soon is i click twitter share then it opens twitter login window. And after few seconds it crashes this happens every time.

Comment: if any help tat u can provide related to it ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41392/discussion-between-sourabh-saldi-and-sagar-kalathil)